# Unable to register my BroadcastReceiver in manifest

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I am having problem in registering my Broadcast Receiver in android manifest file

i have created a BroadcastReceiver which check if the user click the notification its take him to the map activity. The problem is that when i click my notification is disappearing,I think this is due to my broadcasrReceiver not being registered successfully. I am using Eclipse IDE.

Following is my android manifest Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.fyp_api_8_team"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.0" android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

<application
    android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.MyGobalClass"
    android:icon="@drawable/shazam"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.Login_Form"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN.Register_form" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.Register_form"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN.Register_form" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.Forget_form"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN.Forget_form" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.Create_Meeting_Form"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN.Create_Meeting_form" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.Create_Team_Form"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN.Create_Team_Form" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.Map_Location"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN.Map_Location" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN.Main" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.Register_Form"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN.Register_Form" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.MainPreferenceActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.Team_Members"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN.Create_Team_Form..Team_Members" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.Show_Map"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_show__map" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.Services.ScheduleService" />
    <service android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.Services.NotifyService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.MyBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true"></receiver>
</application>
```

This is MyBroadcastReceiver class

```
package com.example.fyp_api_8_team;
 import com.example.fyp_api_8_team.R;
 import com.example.fyp_api_8_team_AlertMap.Show_Map;
 import android.app.Notification;
 import android.app.NotificationManager;
 import android.app.PendingIntent;
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;     
 import android.os.Vibrator;
 import android.util.Log;


    public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
public static int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID;
public static String title, Message;
public static int Meetingid, pos;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(
            R.drawable.stat_notify_more, "You Alarm is here",
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    // take you to the Map class by notification click
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Show_Map.class);

    PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    // Sets the Map class for the particular notification of event
    Show_Map.position = pos;
    notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, title,
            "Click on me to view you Meeting Location", myIntent);

    notifyDetails.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notifyDetails.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);

    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Sucessfully Notification Clicked");

    // Vibrate the mobile phone
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context
            .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(2000);
}
```

}

Comment: your notification disappears because it is FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL. Your activity does not appear because the intent lacks the FLAG_NEW_TASK

Comment: njzk2 i created a sample application when the notification is clicked i took the user to the Person Contact System Service..

Comment: do you have a log or anything that may help ?

Comment: @njzk2 my Logcat is showing no error

Comment: does anything at all happens when you click on that notification ?

Comment: @njzk2 yeah its gets closed !

Comment: and can you post the logcat from this event ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare it like this :

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.fyp_api_8_team.MyBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="**your_action_name**" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: can you be more specific what should i put here. i want the notification to take the user to the Show Map activity